# Connecting to Private Api Gateway from AWS Client VPN user in another AWS Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I've just launched an api in a private api gateway. There's a vpc endpoint for it in the same account, all SGs and resource rules etc are set up.

In another AWS account I own I have an AWS Client VPN set up.

All peering and routing is set up and works between accounts (not relevant I know), but when I try and curl the api from a VPN client, I get:

curl -i https://.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/cross-acc-test
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: .execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com

VPN clients can ping EC2 instances fine so I know clients can traverse the AWS accounts.
VPC DNS hostnames and resolution are enabled.
DNS for the VPN Clients are set to cloudflare and the vpn accounts ip address <*.*.*.2>

stumpted tbh.

Tried everything I can think of.